# Organizing a TXT file

Tags: java

Is there a way to search and organize a txt file without importing the document as a String or Array List?

I am looking for code that would do something like:

Add up all numbers in column 2 for when column 1 equals "2" (when document looks like):

```
2    45    46    89    45
2    65    34    23    89
3    45    65    22    99
```

The file I am using is 20gb long and thus making an Array List once takes about 45 min, then going back through it would take a very long time too.  Trying to make it so that I can just go through the document once and get everything I need.

Comment: Did you considered splitting the file into multiple smaller ones and precessing them all at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the file line by line, split on spaces and add to total if the condition is met.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
String line;
long total = 0;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
    if (tokens[0].equals("2"))
        sum += Long.valueOf(tokens[1]);
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but unfortunately for the other things I need to do in the program (things I did not post in the question so you wouldnt know), it wont work.

Comment: @Danny If this won't work for some reason, please edit your question accordingly. You can't get a right answer if you don't ask the right question.

Comment: I have hundreds of questions that are all relevant to each other.  But, I can't ask all 100 in one stack overflow question.

Comment: Actually, with a little tampering it may.  Thank you